# Create delegate from a constructor of unknown type implementing a known interface

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, code-generation, codedom

I have a type that is created at runtime (through compilation from CodeDOM) and implements a known (at compile time) interface.

Suppose the interface is `IMyInterface`, and I have the Type instance `Type myType` that I acquired from the assembly I just compiled from the CodeDOM. The class that `myType` represents implements `IMyInterface`.

I would like to get a delegate `Func<IMyInterface>` that, when Invoked, will return an instance of `myType`.

Something I would like to call in this way:

```
Func<IMyInterface> createObject = GetObjectCreator<IMyInterface>(myType);
IMyInterface myObject = createObject();
```

I know that if I have a `MethodInfo m` for a parameterless method that returns an instance of myType object, then I could do something like this:

```
Func<IMyInterface> createObject =
  ( Func<IMyInterface> )Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IMyInterface>), m);
```

But if I don't have such a method, and the only thing I have is the type's parameterless constructor, then how do I get this delegate?

## Update

Though fsimonazzi's answer did exactly what I was asking for, my approach was a bit different.

Since I control the creation and compilation of the `myType` Type, I added a public static method that returns an instance of that type. Then, after compiling this type, I got a MethodInfo instance for this method, and created the desired delegate calling Delegate.CreateDelegate.

```
CodeTypeDeclaration type = new CodeTypeDeclaration
{
    Name = "MyClass",
    IsClass = true,
    TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public
};

type.BaseTypes.Add(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(IMyInterface)));

// fullName is the full name of the myType (including namespace)
var staticInstantiator = new CodeMemberMethod
{
    Name = "__Instantiator",
    ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference("MyNamespace.MyClass"),
    Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static
};

staticInstantiator.Statements.Add(
   new CodeMethodReturnStatement(
       new CodeObjectCreateExpression("MyNamespace.MyClass")));

    type.Members.Add(staticInstantiator);
```

The above code generates this code and puts in into the class declaration

```
public static MyNamespace.MyClass __Instantiator()
{
    return new MyNamespace.MyClass();
}
```

Now compiling this code and having a `myType` Type instance for this class, I can do

```
Func<IMyInterface> createObject = ( Func<IMyInterface> )(
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IMyInterface>),
                            myType.GetMethod("__Instantiator")) );

IMyInterface obj = createObject(); // This will call MyClass.__Instantiator()
```

Comment: You are forgetting to actually create the object, call Activator.CreateInstance().

Comment: The whole point is to not use this technique. The GetObjectCreator should return a delegate for a method that would create the instance for me. That method may be compiled at runtime if necessary but I don't want to call Activator.CreateInstance() every time I need an instance.

Comment: You'd better think about that for a while.  A singleton is a bug with a pretty name.

Comment: Who talked about singletons? I would get only one delegate, and I could invoke it a million times getting a million instances of "myType"

Comment: What else are you going to return?  The same object over and over again?  That's that bug with a pretty name.

Comment: You don't understand what I ask for. A method "IMyInterface Create(){ return new myType(); }" is only one method, but returns a new instance every time it is called. The whole problem is that I don't have this method, and I don't know the "myType" at compile time, so I want to create it at runtime. look fsimonazzi's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile a simple lambda expression to get your delegate.

```
var del = Expression.Lambda<Func<IMyInterface>>(Expression.New(type)).Compile();
```

Comment: That doesn't involve any reflection when the delegate is being invoked, right?

Comment: Also, does this line of code compiles and loads an additional assembly in memory?

Comment: No reflection once the delegate is compiled. The method is added to a transient assembly that is shared by all dynamic methods ("Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance( type )` to actually create an instance of your type.  If you want this stuffed in a `Func<IMyInterface>` then you can just wrap it in a lambda:

```
Func<IMyInterface> createObject = () => (IMyInterface) Activator.CreateInstance( myType );
IMyInterface myObject = createObject();
```

UPDATE:

Since `Activator.CreateInstance` is evidently not what you're looking for (though I'm not entirely sure why), I suppose you could use reflection to find the parameterless constructor of the type:

```
public Func<T> GetObjectCreator<T>( Type type )
{
    // I'd probably add additional checks here to see that the
    // conversion to T is actually possible.

    var ctor = type.GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes );

    if( ctor == null ) throw new ArgumentException( "type", "Public parameterless constructor not found." )

    return () => (T) ctor.Invoke( null );
}
```

Comment: Both approaches use reflection at the time of instance creation which is not what I want. The reason I don't want it is that reflection is supposed to be slower than the actual call of the constructor with "new T()", no? So I want to get/create/compile on the fly the function that would call "new T()" (and not ctor.Invoke) and return it. Then, I would take a delegate to this function. So eventually, invoking the delegate would execute "new T()" instead of any other reflection way.

Comment: Well your original question said nothing about not using reflection, please clarify that.  And have you actually profiled the performance of these solutions?  If not, you're just micro-optimizing prematurely.  If that's what you really want, I'd go with the solution given by @fsimonazzi.